# Iptables blocks localhost from accessing redis

Tags: iptables, redis

I have the following iptables rules:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s MY_IP_ADDRESS/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

As you can see, I can ssh into my server from everywhere, and I can access my redis db from my local IP (MY_IP_ADDRESS) and localhost.

From my computer itself, `redis-cli -h xx.xx.xx.xx -p 6379` works. But on the server itself, I cannot connect to the redis db from `redis-cli`.

When I delete the following iptables rule, it works again:

```
-A INPUT -j DROP
```

How can I allow localhost connections to my redis server?

Answer (score 0):

You can add one rule per port:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport some-port -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport another-port -j ACCEPT
```

or add a generic one for all traffic from localhost:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

As a side note, you can get rid of `-A INPUT DROP` as the last rule for `INPUT` if you set `DROP` as a policy: `-P INPUT DROP`

Update: as another side note, actually, if you have `-P OUTPUT ACCEPT`, then there is no need to add any `ACCEPT` rules for `OUTPUT` (you might add rules for `DROP`, for example, but no need for `ACCEPT` because that is what will end up happening with any traffic that goes through `OUTPUT` that is not matching any rule).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I set one rule for localhost + my_external_ip? I tried ```-A INPUT -s MY_IP/32,127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT``` but this does not work either.

Comment: But wait.... this is _source_ address in `INPUT`, right? I do not see why you would consider trying to figure that out by the source address if it is local traffic (in `INPUT` you should not expect to see a lot of traffic that has _your_ ip address in the source). Use the input device with `-i lo`(because even if you try to establish a connection using the IP address of one of your interfaces, traffic _won't_ hit the network interface, it will move around through `lo`).

Comment: Just in case, and assuming you want to do it _regardless_, it should not fail to add the rule the way you have it there (I see no point in having the netmask `/32`, just in case), but in `man iptables` on my debian testing, it says that if you provide multiple addresses/netmasks in `-s`, multiple rules will be added in the end so expect to get 2 separate rules after running that command instead of just one rule.